# To which group is $(\mathbb{Z}\times \mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z})/\langle(1,1,1)\rangle$ isomorphic to?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

$$(\mathbb{Z}\times \mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z})/\langle(1,1,1)\rangle$$

Two elements $(a,b,c), (d,e,f)$ are in the same coset when:

$$(a-d, b-e, c-f) = (k,k,k)\implies a = d+k, b = e+k, c = f+k\implies$$

for each unique choice for $d,e,f$ we have the coset $(d+k, e+k, f+k)$. Examples:

$d=1, e=1, f=1$, coset:

$$\{(-1,-1,-1), (0,0,0),(1,1,1), (2,2,2), (3,3,3),\cdots\}$$

$d=0, e=1, f=1$, coset:

$$\{(-1,0,0),(0,1,1),(1,2,2), (2,3,3), (3,4,4), \cdots\}$$

$d=2, e=0, f=1$, coset:

$$\{(2,0,1), (3, 1, 2), (4, 2, 3), \cdots\}$$

How should I know to which thing this is isomorphic to?

Comment: It's isomorphic to $\Bbb Z\times\Bbb Z$. Have you ever come across the *Smith Normal Form*?

Comment: Hint: Consider using the First Isomorphism Theorem. It very often makes these types of problems much easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint** Define $$f: \mathbb{Z}\times \mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}\times \mathbb{Z} \\
f(a,b,c)=(a-b,a-c)$$

Show that $f$ is an onto group homomorphism. What is its Kernel?

Comment: The kernel is $(a,a,a)$? Then by the isomorphism theorem, we have that the image of this is $\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}$ so it's isomorphic to the quotient, right? But how did you know that you could do $(a-b, a-c)$? Why not just something with image $\mathbb{Z}$? Or even $f(a,b,c) = (a-b, a-c, 7)$. This has image $\mathbb{Z}^2\times\{7\}$... I know it's isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}^2$ but... How did you know?

Comment: @Paprika To use the Isomorphism Theorem you need to define $f: \mathbb{Z}\times \mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z} \to G$ which is onto and has the given Kernel. So you need to define $f(a,b,c)$ in such a way that $f=0$ exactly when $a=b=c$. Next, since we need a kernel, we bring these equalities to the form "something=0": $$a=b \Leftrightarrow a-b=0 \\ a=c \Leftrightarrow a-c=0 $$ So you need to find a linear function such that $$f(a,b,c)=0 \Leftrightarrow a-b=0 \mbox{ and } a-c=0$$

Comment: I quite understood, but why did you take them two by two? It's like you let one variable to be free. That's the part that I don't understand. I've arrived at this one: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2255341/mathbbz-times-mathbbz-times-mathbbz-4-langle3-0-0-rangle-finding, the kernel must be $(3k,0,0)$, that is, $b=0,c=0$ and $a=3k$. How should I proceed with this one?