# $(\mathbb{Z}\times \mathbb{Z}\times \mathbb{Z}_4)/\langle(3,0,0)\rangle$ finding isomorphism and what about a more complex kernel?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

$$(\mathbb{Z}\times \mathbb{Z}\times \mathbb{Z}_4)/\langle(3,0,0)\rangle$$

The group generated by $(3,0,0)$ is infinite. So let's think about the cosets.

Two elements $(a,b,c), (d,e,f)$ are in the same coset when

$$(a-d, b-e, c-f) = (3k,0,0)\implies a = d+3k, b = e, c = f\implies$$

Normally I'd calculate the cosets but this hasn't been much useful. People told me to use the first isomorphism theorem, so I'm trying to find a isomorphism between $\mathbb{Z}\mathbb{Z}\mathbb{Z}_4$ to something such that its kernel is $\{(3k,0,0)\}$. Is it how I'm supposed to think?

I don't know, however, how to find such one. Also, what if I'm asked to find one with kernel like $\{(1k,2k,3k)\}$? Is there a general way to think about it?

Comment: There is a general method of solving problems of this type that involves writing down a matrix and putting it into Smith Normal Form. It would make more sense to learn the general algorithm than to solve a long series of problems by ad hoc methods. Having said that, the answer to this particular problem is pretty obviously $Z_3 \oplus Z \oplus Z_4$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Trying to find a isomorphism between $\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}_4$ to something such that its kernel is {(3k,0,0)} is how you should think about it. We want $3k \mapsto 0$. When are multiples of 3 equal to 0? In $\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}$.

Letting $a \in \mathbb{Z}$, $\overline{a}$ denote modulo by 3, $\tilde{c}$ denote modulo 4, we have the mapping
\begin{equation*}
\varphi: \mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}_4 \to \mathbb{Z}_3 \times \mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}_4 \text{ given by } (a,b,\tilde{c}) \mapsto (\overline{a},b,\tilde{c})
\end{equation*}
You can see that the kernel of $\varphi$ is $\{(3k, 0 ,0): \forall k \in \mathbb{Z}\}$. $\varphi$ is obviously surjective. So, by the first isomorphism theorem, we have 
\begin{equation*}
\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}_4/ \langle(3, 0 ,0)\rangle \cong \mathbb{Z}_3 \times \mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}_4
\end{equation*}

Now, with some more information, we can generalize this to any situation in which we need some arbitrary kernel. For instance, we can see that $\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}/\langle(1,2,3)\rangle \cong 0 \times \mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_3$. What mapping would be associated with this?

Comment: It's because in this case: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2255267/385763 I could have picked like $\mathbb{Z}_1$ instead of $\mathbb{Z}_3$ and it seems it'd work

Comment: I do not understand this comment. What is 'it's' referring to?

Answer (score 1):

The zeros in the last two places tell you the last two components just go along for the ride. As $\Bbb Z/(3)=\Bbb Z_3$ your new group is $\Bbb Z_3 \times \Bbb Z \times \Bbb Z_4$